# jQuery .ajax to Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to convert an ajax request to vanilla JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://foo.bar/hi',
    type: 'post',
    data: {args: params},
    success: function(data){
    },
});
```

I have tried the following

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var data = {args: params};
xhr.open("POST", 'http://foo.bar/hi', true);
xhr.send(data);
```

I am connecting to an external device with a web based interface and not getting any response on the device. It is as if I never sent a request

Theoretically, the original ajax request will perform the action, however, there is a problem with the jQuery portion of my program so I am trying to convert it to vanilla javascript and bypass the jQuery

Comment: What is the response you're getting ?

Comment: Please read the help, and especially how to create a [mcve] - "not getting the response I am expecting" is _not_ a clear problem statement.

Comment: You have not designated an event handler for `onreadystatechange` so how are you getting any sort of response?

Comment: Please read the [docs on `XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). You don’t have anything in your jQuery `success` handler, and you don’t have the equivalent of the `success` callback in your XHR approach.

Comment: @J.Doe do as Paul Abbott is telling you. Designate an event handler for onreadystatechange and come back here and tell us what you're getting.

Comment: @J.Doe What is the problem with your jQuery code? Please, don’t give us new information piece by piece. Read [ask], provide a [mcve] and a complete and actionable problem statement.

Comment: @Xufox I actually have no idea what is wrong with the jQuery side, nor does the developer of the web based device.  We sat down together and decided to just tear out the ajax and begin again without jQuery.

Comment: ajax and jquery are not the same thing - you are not "tearing out the ajax" you are still using ajax, just doing it with vanilla javascript instead of with jquery. Do you get any response attaching to the device with a web browser? How about a command-line `curl`? - since you have no response handlers defined, either in your jquery or your vanilla version, you can't even accurately say that you aren't getting a response.

Comment: Are you set on XMLHttpRequest or are you open to using `fetch`?

Comment: @StephenP, the response would be seen on the external device,

Comment: @RyanZ, if it works, I would take it

Comment: Alright, I will write up an answer.

Comment: @RyanZ, thanks so much, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an AJAX call without jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

Using fetch:

```
function json(response) {
  return response.json();
}

function handleErrors(response) {
  if(!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Request failed " + response.statusText);
  }
  return response;
}

fetch("http://url.com/endpoint", {
  method: "POST",
  body: {
    myKey: "my value",
    another: "hihihi"
  }
}).then(handleErrors).then(json).then(function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}).catch(function(err){
  console.log("err" + err);
})
```

Comment: It is giving me alot of hate about using those =>.  Plus, I assume that I put the {args: params} in the commented section?